# What is a counterexample to the converse of this corollary related to the Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Based on Williams' Probability w/ Martingales:

Let $(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space.

> **Dominated Convergence Theorem**: Suppose $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, $f$ are $\Sigma$-measurable $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$
>    s.t. $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(s) = f(s) \forall s \in S$ or a.e. in S
>    and $\exists g \in \mathscr{L}^1 (S, \Sigma, \mu)$ s.t. $|f_n(s)| \le
>  g(s) \forall s \in S$ (I guess: or a.e. in S). Then $\lim_{n \to
>  \infty} \int_S |f_n - f| d\mu = 0$.

The last sentence implies

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_S f_n d\mu = \int_S f d\mu$$

It is apparently false to say that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_S f_n d\mu = \int_S f d\mu \to \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_S |f_n - f| d\mu = 0$$

Hence, we have things like

> **Scheffé's Lemma Part (i)**: Suppose nonnegative $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, f \in \mathscr{L}^1 (S, \Sigma, \mu)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(s)
>  = f(s) \forall s \in S$ or a.e. in S. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_S |f_n - f| d\mu = 0$ iff $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_S f_n d\mu = \int_S
>  f d\mu$

So what is a counterexample saying that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_S f_n d\mu = \int_S f d\mu$ implies $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_S |f_n - f| d\mu = 0$?

Based on Scheffé's Lemma, I'm guessing a counterexample might have something to do with at least one of the functions not being integrable or something.

---

Re an answer:

$\int_{[-1,1]} |f_n-f|\mathrm d\lambda=2$?

$$\int_{[-1,1]} |f_n-f|\mathrm d\lambda$$

$$ = \int_{[-1,1]} |f_n|\mathrm d\lambda$$

$$ = \int_{[-1,1]} |n1_{(0,1/n)} - n1_{(-1/n,0)}|\mathrm d\lambda$$

$$ \color{red}{=?} \int_{[-1,1]} |n1_{(0,1/n)}| + |n1_{(-1/n,0)}|\mathrm d\lambda$$

$$ = \int_{[-1,1]} n1_{(0,1/n)} \mathrm d\lambda + \int_{[-1,1]} n1_{(-1/n,0)}\mathrm d\lambda$$

$$ = 1 + 1 = 2$$

Comment: Yes, the Scheffe's lemma does not hold if $f \notin \mathscr{L}^1 (S, \Sigma, \mu)$. **Counterexemple**: Let $S=(0,1]$, $\Sigma$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $(0,1]$ and $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure. Let $f$ be defined as $f(x)={1\over x}$. 
For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $f_n =\chi_{[{1 \over n},1]} f$. Then, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $f_n$ is nonnegative and $f_n \in \mathscr{L}^1 (, \Sigma, \mu)$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(s) = f(s) \forall s \in S$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_S f_n d\mu = \int_S f d\mu=+\infty$, BUT, for all $n\in\mathbb{N} $ $\int_S |f_n - f| d\mu =+\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Scheffe's lemma does not hold if $f \notin \mathscr{L}^1 (S, \Sigma, \mu)$.

**Counterexemple**: Let $S=(0,1]$, $\Sigma$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $(0,1]$ and $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure. Let $f$ be defined as $f(x)={1\over x}$. For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $f_n =\chi_{[{1 \over n},1]} f$.

Then, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $f_n$ is nonnegative and $f_n \in \mathscr{L}^1 (S, \Sigma, \mu)$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(s) = f(s) \forall s \in S$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_S f_n d\mu = +\infty = \int_S f d\mu$, BUT, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\int_S |f_n - f| d\mu =+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks Ramiro. How do you know you can swap $\lim$ and $\int$? Also how do you evaluate $\int_S |f_n - f| d\mu$?

Comment: @BCLC **1**. In the counterexemple  above, we do NOT swap $\lim$ and $\int$.  We evaluate $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_S f_n d\mu =\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_S \chi_{[{1\over n},1]} \frac{1}{x} d\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[{1 \over n},1]} \frac{1}{x} d\mu =\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln n = +\infty$$ and we evaluate $$\int_S f d\mu =\int_{(0,1]}\frac{1}{x}= +\infty$$ So we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_S f_n d\mu =+\infty=\int_S f d\mu$$ **2**. To evaluate $\int_S |f_n - f| d\mu$: 
$$ \int_S |f_n - f| d\mu = \int_S \chi_{(0, {1 \over n})} f d\mu  = \int_{(0, {1 \over n} )} \frac{1}{x} d\mu=+\infty$$
OK?

Comment: I thought you swapped based on your comment in OP. hehe thanks Ramiro ^-^

Comment: @BCLC  Well, we can also see  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_S f_n d\mu = +\infty = \int_S f d\mu$$ as a swap of $\lim$ and $\int$.  To justify such swap, note that  for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $f_n$ is nonnegative and $f_n \in \mathscr{L}^1 (S, \Sigma, \mu)$ and $f_n$ converges monotonically to $f$. So we can apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem and conclude that  
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_S f_n d\mu =  \int_S f d\mu$$
However, since we know explicitly the functions and their integrals are easy to evaluate, it is simpler to do just the direct evaluation (as in my previous comment).

Comment: MCT needs integrability? I don't think Wiki says so

Comment: I didn't say MCT needs integrability.  It would be enough that $f_n$ be nonnegative measurable functions. However, in the counterexemple,  $f_n \in \mathscr{L}^1 (S, \Sigma, \mu)$ and so it is immediate that $f_n$ are measurable functions. Did you understand why it is possible to apply MCT in this case?

Comment: Because measurability is needed and integrability implies measurability? Kind of weird. Iirc, you need a function first to be measurable before you can begin to say it is integrable? So when you say a function is integrable in some measure space, the function by definition is measurable in that measure space...I think?

Comment: @BCLC There is nothing weird. For any function $g$ , $g\in \mathscr{L}^1 (S, \Sigma, \mu)$  implies $g$ measurable in $(S, \Sigma, \mu)$. In the counterexexample,  we defined $f_n =\chi_{[{1 \over n},1]} \frac{1}{x}$ and we claimed that $f_n\in \mathscr{L}^1 (S, \Sigma, \mu)$. Of course, in this claim is included the claim that $f_n$ are measurable, otherwise they would not be in $\mathscr{L}^1 (S, \Sigma, \mu)$.

Comment: Okay thanks Ramiro ^-^

Answer (score 4):

A potential counter-example with pointwise convergence cannot be a sequence which is dominated by an integrable function.

For example, we can consider the interval $[-1,1]$ endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the Lebesgue measure and the functions $f_n:=-n\mathbf 1_{(-1/n,0)}+n\mathbf 1_{(0,1/n)}$, $n\geqslant 1$. Then $f_n(s)\to f(s):=0$ for each $s\in [-1,1]$ and $\int_{[-1,1]} f_n\mathrm d\lambda=0=\int_{[-1,1]} f\mathrm d\lambda$. However, $\int_{[-1,1]} |f_n-f|\mathrm d\lambda=2$.

Comment: There are counterexamples with pointwise convergence and nonnegative sequences.   In such counterexemples, $\int_S f d\mu=+\infty$.

Comment: @Ramiro Right, I removed this part of the sentence.

Comment: Indeed one can see such an example by simply adding $n$ to Davide's example.

Comment: @Ian Not so easy, since you can not simply add $n$ to $f$.

Comment: @Ramiro I meant to $f_n$.

Comment: @Ian If  you  add $n$ to $f_n$, then $f$ would need to be $+\infty\chi_{[-1,1]}$. It is OK, but it would make the counterexample rather "artificial". There are simpler and more natural counterexamples.

Comment: @Ramiro I misspoke twice, in fact: I meant to add $n \chi_{(-1/n,1/n)}$ to $f_n$. Then $f_n=2n \chi_{(0,1/n)} \geq 0$ and $f$ is still zero.

Comment: @Ian But then, for all $n$,  $\int_{[-1,1]}f_n d\mu=2$  and they do not converge to $\int_{[-1,1]}f d\mu=0$.

Comment: @Ramiro Ah, hm, OK, I stand corrected then.

Comment: Thanks Davide Giraudo. How do you know that $\int_{[-1,1]} |f_n-f|\mathrm d\lambda=2$? Pls see my edit

Comment: The "?" follows from the fact that if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint sets, then $|a\mathbf 1_A+b\mathbf 1_B| =|a|\mathbf 1_A+|b|\mathbf 1_B$.