# convergence of expectation sum of infinite random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, expectation, independence

If $X_n$ are independent random variables such that $\sum \mathbb{E} X_n$ exists,
  and that $\sum X_n$ converges a.s. (almost surely), must it be that $\mathbb{E} \sum X_n = \sum
  \mathbb{E} X_n$?

If $X_n \ge 0$, then this is obvious by using monotone convergence theorem since $\sum_{n=1}^{N} X_n$ is non-decreasing. Also, [we know the following three things from $\sum X_n$ converges a.s.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem)

1).$\sum\mathbb{P}(|X_n|>1)<\infty$

2).$\sum\mathbb{E}Y_n<\infty$, where $Y_n=X_n\mathbb{1}_{|X_n|\le 1}$

3).$\sum Var(Y_n)<\infty$

I am stuck on this problem and don't know how to proceed. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Rann, edited answer

Answer (score 2):

It holds [if](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519751/why-cant-fubinis-tonellis-theorem-for-non-negative-functions-extend-to-genera) $E[|\sum X_i|] < \infty$ or $E[\sum |X_i|] < \infty$.

---

Consider $X_1, X_2, ...$ in $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathbb P) = ([0,1], \mathscr B([0,1]), \lambda)$ where

$$X_n = 2^n 1_{A_n} + -2^{n} 1_{B_n} + 01_{A_n^C \cap B_n^C}$$ where $\lambda(A_n) = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} = \lambda(B_n)$ and $A_i \cap B_j = A_n \cap B_n = A_i \cap A_j = B_i \cap B_j = \emptyset$

We have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n < \infty \ \lambda-a.s.$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} E[X_n] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 0 = 0$$

But we cannot compute

$$E [\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n ]$$

because we have

$$ E [| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n |]$$

$$= E [|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^n 1_{A_n} + -2^{n} 1_{B_n}|] $$

[$$= E [\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |2^n| 1_{A_n} + |-2^{n}| 1_{B_n}] $$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498400/what-is-a-counterexample-to-the-converse-of-this-corollary-related-to-the-domina/1498604?noredirect=1#comment3165160_1498487)

$$= E [\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2^n 1_{A_n} + 2^{n} 1_{B_n})] $$

Note that $(2^n 1_{A_n} + 2^{n} 1_{B_n}) \ge 0$. Hence:

$$= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} E [(2^n 1_{A_n} + 2^{n} 1_{B_n})] $$

$$= \infty$$

---

I think the above is independent of whether or not the random variables are independent.